# Are all blocks/transactions available using geth "snap" sync method?

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to run blockbook (https://github.com/trezor/blockbook) node which uses `geth` as an Ethereum client.

Will there be all necessary information (blocks, tx details) to build blockbook db if I use \ `geth`'s default "snap" synchronization method?

I am getting conflicting information (or maybe I am just misunderstanding the information) about full vs archive nodes and the way they synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've learned (and tested) the syncMode or just *mode* (snap/full) does not matter. It is just a way to get to the synced state.

What I've encountered (couldn't access old transactions) was due to the default limit on the number of transactions kept in the index.

When you run `geth --txlookuplimit=0` it will be able to serve all transactions.